# Could I refactor this?

Tags: c

I have `struct analyzer_t` and `analyzers_t`, where I have 3 variables of type `analyzer_t`.  `analyzers_t` occurs more times in the code and I must write /call everything 3 times but with small differences. I'm attaching `writeFiles` as an example.
Anyone could give me a clue if(and if, then how) could I refactor this? I though about putting an array  in `analyzers_t`. But as I said, I call functions(see what I mean in `writeFiles` )in somewhat different way.

```
typedef struct analyzer_t
{
  unsigned char *buff;
  size_t StartPosition;

}analyzer_t;


typedef struct analyzers_t
{
  analyzer_t analyzer1;
  analyzer_t analyzer2;
  analyzer_t analyzer3;
  unsigned char *Sequence;
}analyzers_t;



int writeFiles(char *name, analyzers_t *analyzers )
{
  if (analyzers->analyzer1.StartPosition > 10)writeFile(name,
       analyzers->analyzer1.buff, &analyzers->analyzer1.StartPosition, dir1);
  if (analyzers->analyzer2.StartPosition > 10)writeFile(name, 
       analyzers->analyzer2.buff, &analyzers->analyzer2.StartPosition, dir2);
  if (analyzers->analyzer3.StartPosition > 10)writeFile(name, 
       analyzers->analyzer3.buff, &analyzers->analyzer3.StartPosition, dir3);

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Seems better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have an array of three `analyzer_t` in your `analyzers_t`, then you can iterate the array an call the same function for each.

Comment: I though about putting an array in analyzers_t. But as I said, I call functions(see what I mean in writeFiles )in somewhat different way.

Comment: @Mamu If you put both dir1-3 and analyzer1-3 in arrays you can use a loop instead of 3 different statements.

Comment: I know, but it is only an example. As I said it occurs more times in the code and I'd need to put a lot of extra  variables in analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

Do the common stuff in function and pass only the differing information:

```
void writeAnalyzer(analyzer_t * analyzer, char * name, char * dir) {
    if (analyzer->StartPosition > 10)
        writeFile(name, analyzer->buff, &analyzer->StartPosition, dir);
}
```

And don't use suffix `_t` with custom types. Those are reserved for standard C library.

Comment: What may not be obvious to the OP is that the parameter dir allows calling this in a loop. Declare an array instead of single analyzers and loop through the elements, passing the dir (also from an array?) into user694733's function. Better: Make dir a and writeAnalyzer() members in analyzer_t. Of course the function then doesn't need an analyzer_t * arg any longer; that's then "this".

Comment: Oh; this is C. Sorry, no member functions ;-). But the dirs should still be in the type.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Yes, I agree. Making dir a member of analyzer, and calling the function in loop would would make it more simple.